# What exactly is a .base.cs file extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

What exactly is a .base.cs file extension? How is it different from a regular .cs class file? And how is it used differently? I used a code generation tool, and this is what it generated, and the project builds, but I'm not sure what they are made with .base.cs and not just .cs - the classes are all partial classes, not sure if that is a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an extension used by the code generation tool to ensure that the name of the generated file doesn't conflict with any existing file in your project. Since the generated classes are `partial` you could create your own code file with the same name (minus the `.base`) to extend them. For example:

```
MyClass.base.cs   // classes created by the code generator
MyClass.cs        // custom extensions to the generated classes
```

It will compile just like any other code file.

Comment: does it affect anything? I can use it like a regular .cs file?

Comment: @M.R.: File names are irrelevant to the C# compiler. You can call it MyClass.Giraffe if you want; the compiler will take it.